# Add on to an older question about how to make a text print 1 sentence on each line

Tags: python

So basically I got the answer for how to have each sentence of a text printed on a different line using replace "." with /n, but I also want to add a delay in between each line being printed using the time.sleep function. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just do this:

```
s = 'this is. the text. that you. want to separate'.split('.')
for line in s:
    time.sleep(...)
    print(line)
```